How to resolve ValueError: You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method that includes input_ids, but you provided []
This is my first time using datasets to train an AI and I can't figure out this error. The model takes in .txt files and convert them into .json.
This code snippet fine-tunes a BERT model for Named Entity Recognition (NER) using the Hugging Face transformers library. It begins by loading an NER dataset from disk and then initializes a BERT model and tokenizer, configured specifically for the dataset's labels. The code defines a metric computation function to evaluate the model's performance in terms of precision, recall, F1 score, and accuracy using the seqeval library. It sets up training parameters, such as learning rate and batch size, and configures the Trainer class for model training. After training, the code saves both the fine-tuned model and tokenizer.
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForTokenClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments, DataCollatorForTokenClassification
from datasets import load_from_disk
import evaluate

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_from_disk('ner_dataset')

# Check the dataset format
print(f"Dataset features: {dataset['train'].features}")

# Load the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_labels=len(dataset['train'].features['labels'].feature.names))

# Load the metric
metric = evaluate.load('seqeval')

def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=2)

    # Convert indices to label names
    true_labels = [
        [dataset['train'].features['labels'].feature.names[l] for l in label if l != -100]
        for label in labels
    ]
    true_predictions = [
        [dataset['train'].features['labels'].feature.names[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]

    # Compute and return metrics
    results = metric.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        'precision': results['overall_precision'],
        'recall': results['overall_recall'],
        'f1': results['overall_f1'],
        'accuracy': results['overall_accuracy'],
    }

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./training_results',
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    num_train_epochs=4,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=1,
    save_steps=5_000,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=500,
)

# Initialize the Trainer with a data collator that handles token classification
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer=tokenizer, pad_to_multiple_of=8)

# Print sample data to check formatting
print(f"Sample data: {dataset['train'][0]}")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=dataset['validation'],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()

# Save the model and tokenizer
trainer.save_model('fine-tuned-ner-model')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('fine-tuned-ner-model')

print("Model and tokenizer saved successfully to 'fine-tuned-ner-model'")

Traceback error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\bert_model\train_bert.py", line 72, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1938, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2236, in _inner_training_loop
    for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\data_loader.py", line 454, in __iter__
    current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 630, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 673, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 55, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self.torch_call(features)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 333, in torch_call
    batch = pad_without_fast_tokenizer_warning(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 66, in pad_without_fast_tokenizer_warning     
    padded = tokenizer.pad(*pad_args, **pad_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "BERT_Receipt_Model\new_env\Lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 3497, in pad
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method that includes input_ids, but you provided []
  0%|          | 0/16 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

